# Is it possible to make the heading on a page different text to the text of the menu item?

Tags: menus

Is it possible to make the heading on a page different text to the text of the menu item?

I have a page with a very long title and I'd like to make the clickable menu text shorter.

Site is here: http://richardclunan.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into Apparences -> Menu -> (find the header menu) -> Click the page you want to change, when the options open, just change the heading label to whatever you want.

Regards